# How to change UISegmentedControl index with animation?

Tags: ios, animation, uisegmentedcontrol

I can change selected segment of `UISegmentedControl` by `selectedSegmentIndex`, however is it possible to change index with animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You have to implement your own custom view or search for a 3rd party control that allows that.