# How to animate Segmented Control selection?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` with 3 possible selections and I have added a coloured underline bar to the first selection. I'm trying to figure out how to animate the underline so that it moves to highlight the new selection, but the underline bar is not moving.

I'm not looking to change the index with animation. I'm trying to figure out how to keep the underline bar UIView in the same segment that is selected. I've seen this implemented commonly.

Here's a screen recording of what's happening right now - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw5e9.jpg

I added the `UISegmentedControl` via `Storyboard` and then added the underline in code with view.addSubview(underlineBar). Here's is what I have:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            setSegmentedControlStyle()   
        }

    func setSegmentedControlStyle() {
            segmentedControl.backgroundColor = .clear
            segmentedControl.tintColor = .clear
            segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray
                ], for: .normal)
            segmentedControl.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16),
                NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue
                ], for: .selected)

let underlineBar = UIView()
            underlineBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // false since we are using auto layout constraints
            underlineBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            view.addSubview(underlineBar)

            underlineBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            underlineBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
            underlineBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            underlineBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                underlineBar.frame.origin.x = (self.segmentedControl.frame.width / CGFloat(self.segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
            }
        }

    }
```

The `UIView.animate` is being called, but nothing happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36379244/10150796

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change UISegmentedControl index with animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379008/how-to-change-uisegmentedcontrol-index-with-animation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting constraints for **underlineBar** that are updating the X, Y and width, height properties so when you are trying to animate the change in position, the view is not moving because the constraints have higher priority. In conclusion you will need to animate the constraints.

I have created a global **leftAnchor** that you will modify every time the segment is pressed.

```
var underlineBarLeftAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Where you setup your constraints update the function with this:

```
underlineBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
underlineBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true
underlineBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1 / CGFloat(segmentedControl.numberOfSegments)).isActive = true

underlineBarLeftAnchor = underlineBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.leftAnchor, constant: 0)
underlineBarLeftAnchor.isActive = true
```

Now you will need to register the target-action methods for a segmented control using the **valueChanged** constant as shown below, update **viewDidLoad()**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setSegmentedControlStyle()
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateSegmentedControl), for: .valueChanged)

}
```

Last step, create the **updateSegmentedControl()** function where you will animate the movement:

> This function will get called every time the value of the segment control is changed

```
@objc func updateSegmentedControl() {
    let padding = underlineBar.frame.width * CGFloat(self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    underlineBarLeftAnchor.constant = padding

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

You need to calculate how much left padding you need and then update the ui, **layoutIfNeeded()**, while animating the change.

Comment: Thank you for laying this out for me. I do get an error when I run this: ""<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000298240 UIView:0x7fc0c470dfd0.left == UISegmentedControl:0x7fc0c4724fd0.left   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000298ec0 UIView:0x7fc0c470dfd0.left == UISegmentedControl:0x7fc0c4724fd0.left + 105   (active)>" ". So its getting 2 values for the leftanchor and so not animating and breaking one?

Comment: That's happens because you are setting another leftAnchor constraint, besides the underlineBarLeftAnchor, make sure you have deleted your old underlineBar.leftAnchor.

Comment: I have 3 segment controls and it looks like I was trying to add this to all of them via the same method which caused additional leftAnchor constraints. Thank you very much again